# Water comes out of the shower head when faucet is in tub fill mode (I know why, but not how to fix)

Tags: plumbing, shower, bathtub

Here is the deal - I got bathroom remodeled. Moen 82603 single handle valve. When the water is coming out the fastest (mixing hot/cold) water comes out of the shower head. The person (not me) I had helping installed the valve at about 48" from tub floor or about 30" above faucet. The directions clearly stated the valve can't be more than 11" above the faucet. So basically the new shower wall is toast since if I have to have this re-done, and the valve lowered, it's a complete re-do.

Question?  What are some better options? I can get into the plumbing by removing the drywall in the adjacent room.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the problem is just the diverter on your tub spout, it's probably not opening all the way, which allows some back pressure to build up in the pipe that eventually gets back up to the shower head. It could also be corrosion inside of the pipe that is having the same effect. [image]

I don't see how it would have anything to do with the height of the valve, unless maybe the lack of head pressure (weight of the column of water in the pipe) isn't enough to overcome the back pressure created by your diverter valve. The Moen valve is just on or off, it doesn't tell the water which way to go, that's done with the diverter.

If that doesn't do it, the other option would be to put a shut-off valve at the shower head spout. Same net effect, no need to open the wall.

[image]

Comment: I don't think its the diverted, I bought a new spout and still have the problem. However if I run it without the spout, the shower doesn't come on.  Would it cause grief if the quick shut off is off and someone tries to run the shower?

Comment: The grief would be that they want a shower and there is no water coming from it... It's hard to get clean that way!

Comment: Yes those measurements are so you don't get water coming from the shower head. How did that get up voted 4 times?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @J.Raefield, a showerhead shutoff which can be added to the existing showerhead [such as this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westbrass-Volume-Control-in-Chrome-for-Shower-Arm-D309-26/203881561):
[image]

Otherwise, replace the showerhead with a model which includes a shutoff valve.

Answer (score 1):

I changed out the pex to copper. here is my vid

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1XEo60a3OSw

Comment: Hello, welcome back, and thanks for giving us the update. However, it's hard for people to get your answer without watching the while four-minute video. Would you include the pertinent info in your answer text? (E.g., why did changing PEX to copper help?)

Comment: Did it fix it? See also https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/21150/11265

Answer (score 0):

You're in a tough spot. Adding a shut off above will work but that would drive me nuts. Some other options are opening the drywall behind a doing 1 of two things.
1- change the downspout to as much 3/4"pipe as possible. That way your newly finished shower can stay that way. (might not work)
2 - add two ball valves on the hot and cold entering the Moen, turn the water on and close them off slowly until water stops coming out of the shower head.
You could get better results doing both.

The shower head has a built in water saver so you shouldn't notice too much pressure drop.