# Shower head drips while filling tub

Tags: shower, water-pressure

I was reading a previous post and I have the same problem. Filling the tub and water comes from the shower head. Wife hates it. We used pex from the valve to both outlets with drop ear 90s. The tub spout was not set right so we used copper pipe with sweat on male adapters to get the right length, brass nipples were either too long or short. Walls are all sealed up and I'm not sure what to do to fix this, i need to make the wife happy

Comment: Before you go tearing into walls, make sure there is no restriction in the tub spout or the output from the valve.  If that looks OK, then the next most likely issue is that there is an issue or blockage in the tub/shower valve.  Not a pleasing prospect of tearing into it.  Sometimes it's easier to get at it from the other side.

Comment: I will check, everything was new so I don't believe there is a clog but it's possible. From what I've read it seams to be i don't have enough flow coming out of the spout so it diverts to the shower. I wonder if I replace the 1/2 copper in the spout with 3/4 if that would work

Comment: This answered question seems to favor the idea that it's due to restriction in lines but I can't imagine why too little flow coming out of the tub spout would cause it to divert to the shower:

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20813/why-does-my-shower-head-drip-when-the-tub-faucet-is-on?rq=1

Comment: I suggest pulling the valves from the faucet and flushing the lines. It could be that there s a sand/grit/calcium blockage.